# Transfering Contacts from Icloud to Iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud

My brother and I shared the same apple ID, so all of my contacts from icloud are under his apple ID.I got a new Iphone using my OWN apple id. How do I get my contacts from his icloud onto my iphone?

Answer (score 2):

- Log into your brother's iCloud account on your iPhone
- Wait for the contacts to sync
- Disable Contacts syncing in Settings and choose to keep the data
- Re-login into your own iCloud account
- Merge existing contacts (the ones on your phone) into the account